# Shared Element Transitions not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-transitions

I'm trying to create a simple `shared element transition` between two activities that share the same image. My goal is to have the clicked image in the *First Activity* expand to fill the top portion of the screen of the *Second Activity*.

The ***First Activity*** contains a `ViewPager` with two `Fragments`. In each of these fragments, there is a `RecylerView` that contains a bunch of `Cards`. Each of these cards contains the image that, if clicked, will expand and become the large image in the *Second Activity*.

The Second Activity contains an `ImageView` that takes up the upper portion of the screen. This is the view that the image from the *First Activity* should become.

I've tried looking at similar questions and the *SharedElementTransitions* documentation, however everything I do seems to produce the same, buggy result.

This is currently what happens *(**Note**: In this video example I've attempted to make the round image and the large background image of the selected card transition between activities)* : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3g96VyLidSVeEY5YTc1eWhOMDQ/view

This is kind of what I'd like to have happen:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97787025/device-2015-06-03-114842.mp4

If someone wants, I can post my code, however I think I just don't understand the fundamentals behind how this shared Element Transition is working, so I'm not sure how much help my code will be. If you need any more information please let me know, and thanks!

Comment: hi there, I know it has been 10 month since you ask it but... did you got it :D ?. If not, let me know to see if I can help you. By the way take a look at [this link](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2014/12/activity-fragment-transitions-in-android-lollipop-part1.html) if you need some explanation about this topic.